# как добавить файлы в коммит из pre-commit хука в git 1.9.5?

Tags: git, git-commit

Необходимо научить `git v1.9.5` перед коммитом транспилировать определенные файлы из одной директории в другую и после этого уже делать коммит.

так как в коммит попадают файлы после `git add` а на `git add` хуки не придумали, то получается что после того как моя утилита вызывается из `pre-commit` хука и делает все что необходимо, файлы сгенерированные ей не попадают в коммит.

`win xp (x86)`

Есть ли решение?

Comment: использовать `git mv <file>` ? Но только не пойму, зачем такой изврат нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim изврат нужен для того что бы иметь возможность юзать гит для ert-файлов 1c 7.7 которые должны транспилироваться с помощью gcomp

Comment: @KoVadim можете подробнее сказать как я могу использовать mv для того что бы добавить файлы в коммит? Если я правильно понял то эта команда просто переносит файлы из одной директории в дргую

Comment: я недочитал вопрос. В прекоммит хуке делать git add пробовали для новых файлов? а вообще то подобное не делается. А если нужны новые файлы, применяют деплой скрипты.

Comment: @KoVadim в pre-commit хуке я вызываю exe-шник который делает некую магию после которой ert-файлы разбираются в набор файлов. Затем в том же хуке я пишу `git add .` но файлы не добавляются в коммит.

Comment: `git add .` достаточно опасная команда. Можно и лишнего добавить. Я бы делал более явно. И конечно же посмотрел, что оно в правильном каталоге запускается.

Comment: 1. а что значит «транспилировать»? 2. *но файлы не добавляются в коммит* — вероятно, срабатывает `.gitignore` / `.git/info/exclude` / `~/.gitignore`. попробуйте указывать файлы явно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin транспилировать означает примерно то что из одного файла получается другой, в моем случае бинарный ert превращается в набор текстовых и табличных файлов для того что бы можно было понять какие именно изменения были сделаны с кодом. гитигнора нет, это не про это.

Comment: ещё две гипотезы: 1. скрипт вообще выполняется? 2. скрипт возвращает `0` в качестве кода возварата? (`exit 0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример файла `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, который просто копирует новые/модифицированные (можно и другие — см. [`man git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) на предмет значений для опции `--diff-filter`) файлы из каталога `dir1` в каталог `dir2` (и добавляет их «внутрь» коммита):

```
#!/bin/sh

from=dir1
to=dir2

mkdir -p $to
for f in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep "^$from/"); do
  n=$(echo $f | sed "s.^$from.$to.")
  cp $f $n
  git add $n
done 

exit 0
```

вместо копирования, конечно, можно производить и более полезные действия.

---

про способ отбора файлов подсмотрено в этом ответе: [Git pre-commit hook : changed/added files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068990/4827341)

Comment: уверены ли вы что `git add $n` будет работать для версии гит указанной в вопросе?

Comment: именно этой версии под рукой нет. пользуюсь версией 1.7.10.4, сейчас проверил на версии 2.1.4. в обоих случаях результат — аналогичный: работает, как и ожидается. протестируйте сами на новом репозитории/другой машине.

Comment: ОС win xp 32, и этот скрипт не работает

Comment: *win* — а, тогда понятно. могу лишь посочувствовать вашим затруднениям..

Comment: не работают конкретно строчка с `for` (при добавлении нового файла в директорию dir1 diff видимо не видит этого и тело цикла не отрабатывает). Если заменить на  `for f in $from; do` то строка `n=$(echo $f | sed "s.^$from.$to.")` падает по ошибке.

Comment: прежде чем что-то менять, просто проверьте: создайте пустое хранилище, пустой файл, добавьте его в индекс: `git add файл` и посмотрите, что вам выдаёт `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM`

Comment: попробуйте проверить на более предсказуемой операционной системе. `gnu/linux`, например.

Comment: на линуках работает, смысл как раз в том что есть ИС которую писали 10 лет, где милионы строк кода на 1с7.7 и ОС на всех рабочих станциях, коих с десяток тысяч, win xp - это является жестким ограничением.

Comment: может ли не срабатывать `for f in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM | grep "^$from/"); do` для бинарных файлов?

Comment: В итоге проблема была решена только через отдельное добавление каждого измененного файла, а не общей командой добавить все из директории куда складывались файлы после транспиляции, поэтому буду считать что ваш ответ принят, так как он натолкнул меня сделать именно так. с вашего скрипта пригодилась только идея. Спасибо.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin вы тем не менее можете опубликовать собственный ответ. А ещё мне интересно, если я добавил (git add) какой-то файл, а потом его содержимое поменял, то какая версия будет обрабатываться - которая в индексе или которая на диске?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, та, которая сохранена в индексе после последнего `git add`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а откуда берётся содержимое этой версии? Смотрю на код и вроде бы вижу, что будет копироваться версия из рабочей области.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а вы создайте пустое хранилище, `$ echo 1> file; git add file`, и увидите, что в `.git/objects` появился новый объект. вот это и есть *blob* с новым файлом (посмотреть тип: `$ git cat-file -t хэш`, содержимое: `$ git cat-file -p хэш`). именно этот *blob* и будет задействован при создании объекта *commit*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, я это уже проделывал не раз. Прошёл весь путь и вижу, что копируется файл из рабочей области, а не из индекса. Где я не прав? https://gist.github.com/NickVolynkin/f91289d2924b96109d6af6e2bee2bb82

Comment: Т.е. в коммите конечно окажется тот блоб, на который указывает дерево текущего индекса. Но в процессе работы хука нам нужно копировать (или сделать что угодно ещё) файлы. И если мы хотим закоммитить одновременно исходное и конечное состояние файлов, то есть риск получить несоответствующие версии. Исходное будет от последнего git add вручную, а конечное - от того, что прямо сейчас в рабочей области.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тьфу, прошу прощения, я не понял, о каком именно процессе добавления речь. в хуке, изложенном в ответе, копируется, конечно, содержимое файла из *рабочей копии*. чтобы копировалось из индекса, надо как-то вычислить хэш объекта. и `cat-file -p` на него натравить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а вычислить хэш можно, например, с помощью `$ git ls-files -s [-- имя.файла]`.